# how to update chart with variable?

Tags: excel, vba

Hope someone can help I'm having trouble with something that should be really simple.

I'm trying to update a chart based on changing source data (number of rows can change)

this is my code:

```
lastRow = GetLastRow(ChartSourceSheet)
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("ChartSource").Range("A1:C" & lastRow)
```

for some reason it doesn't work (getlastrow function is just a function that returns the last row number of a sheet, in this case it's 5 with my test data)

but if i hard code the change it to:

```
lastRow = 5
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("ChartSource").Range("A1:C" & lastRow)
```

then it works absolutely fine, and it's driving me nuts trying to figure out why.

I've tried declaring lastRow as integer but it doesn't work.

Anybody have any ideas what I can try?

edit in response to replies:

doesn't work means the chart just doesn't update and when I look at the data range manually it hasn't updated (in comparison to when i hardcoded the value and it updated fine) Also I tried setting lastRow to long as well and that didn't help.

My function works fine, as it's returning the expected value (5) but for completion purposes here's the code to my function:

```
Function GetLastRow(sheetName As Worksheet)
GetLastRow = 1
On Error Resume Next
GetLastRow = sheetName.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Exactly what does "doesn't work" stand for? Also, `lastRow` should be declared `As Long`, not `As Integer`. Worksheets can have many times more rows than can fit in a 16-bit signed integer type.

Comment: You will need to post the code for your function as it is obviously the problem.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55031722/edit) to add the code -- it's just to difficult to properly parse when in comments

Comment: sorry i'm still quite new to stackoverflow and realised that after putting in a comment with code

Comment: How do you know your function is returning the correct value? did you do a debug.print and check the immediate window?

Comment: Your code seemed to work for me. If you can post the specific error you are getting and the line of code that is breaking, then that would help.

Answer (score 0):

You should likely make sure that `GetLastRow()` returns a `Long` variable:

```
Sub doChart()
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = GetLastRow(Sheets("Sheet1")) ' Change to whatever you need
' Next line requires the chart to be active.  You'd be better off actually directly
' calling it, but that's for you to tweak. If there's only one chart, 
' then try Charts(1).SetSourceData ...
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("ChartSource").Range("A1:C" & lastRow)
End Sub

Function GetLastRow(sheetName As Worksheet) As Long
GetLastRow = 1
GetLastRow = sheetName.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
End Function
```

Also, I removed the `On Error ...` in the function, because there shouldn't be any errors, and if there are it'd be best to handle.  (Worst case is that would return `1` as far as I can tell)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments and advice

Managed to figure it out in the end.
It's because I was deleting the cells that the graph was referring to

ws.cells.delete

i changed this to

ws.cells.clear

and there was no longer a problem.

Comment: Glad you solved it. Often when you ask a question, the solution will somehow pop out by "itself"....